# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/mysql.so'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, laravel

I recently installed EHCP with all the necessary packages and now everytime I try to run my laravel project by typing **php artisan serve**, I get the following error:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php/20151012/mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/mysql.so:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown
>   on line 0

Please help, thank you.

Comment: ^ The opposite actually.  Seems like you have an outdated extension line in your php.ini

Comment: What's your php version?

Comment: As pointed out by @Devon, it's an outdated extension line: the API number in the path is for 7.0.X, for which there is no mysql extension as it was removed.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the mysql extension installed? If not, you may need to install it.

```
apt-get install php-mysql
```

In ubuntu 16.04 and above (as I can remember), this will install the module for PHP7 by default. So you need to check your php version and install the relevant one.

Ex: `apt-get install php5.6-mysql`

Then check you have the module installed by running:

```
php -m | grep mysql
```

Hope it helps!